# Passing a matrix as an parameter to a function in R programming language

Tags: r, function, matrix, arguments

**Is it possible to pass an entire (square) matrix as the argument of a function in R ?**

I mean, what I want is that while running the programme, an user will create his / her desired matrix (Say `A`) in the R console, and if the name of the function is `cdecom` (Created by me) , the user will write `cdecom(A)` to get the required output. A possible demonstration of the input by an user is as follows :

```
A <- matrix( 1:25 , nrow=5 , byrow=TRUE)
cdecom(A)
```

Is this somehow possible ? Thanks in advance. (If my question is unclear, please see the 3rd comment)

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what exactly you are asking. There are countless functions that take matrices as arguments, one example would be `diag()`

Comment: Basically, the function ```cdecom``` is created by me. While I'm writing
```cdecom <- function(mat)``` , I need to let the R console know that ```mat``` is actually a matrix because I'm using matrix operations on ```mat``` inside the body. How would I make the R console know that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `class(A)=="matrix"` and `stopifnot` within your function `cdecom` like below

```
cdecom <- function(A) {
  stopifnot(class(A)=="matrix")
  ...
}
```

Comment: So, inside the function, can I write functions which are used for matrix operations ? For example, can I use ```det(A)``` or ```A[1,n]``` inside the function body ?

Comment: @JRC If `A` is a matrix, then the line `stopifnot(class(A)=="matrix")` will be skipped, such that you can go to next steps, e.g., `det(A)` or `A[1,n]`. Otherwise, `stopifnot(class(A)=="matrix")` will be triggered and function exits

Comment: I was thinking if I write ```mat <- as.matrix(mat)``` inside the function, will that help ?

Comment: I guess my problem has been solved. Thank you.

Comment: @JRC `as.matrix` is valid only if you know that the class of `mat` is available to be converted to  `matrix`. If not,  then `mat <- as.matrix(mat)` might pop up an error such that you cannot move ahead

Comment: Ohh understood ! Thanks @ThomasIsCoding. :D